# Does xoshiro/xoroshiro PRNGs provide uniform distribution?

Tags: random, distribution, uniform-distribution

It's not clear from the [documentation](https://prng.di.unimi.it/) if the sequence of integers produced by these PRNGs belongs to the uniform distribution.

Also it's look like there is a whole family of RNG algorithms called in a similar manner. Personally I'm mostly interested in [`xoshiro256**`](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/a-quick-look-at-xoshiro256.html) - but no information about distribution uniformity as well.

Comment: David Blackman and Sebastiano Vigna, "Scrambled Linear Pseudorandom Number Generators." *ACM TOMS*, Vol. 47, No. 4, Dec. 2021, Article 36, pp. 1–32: "Proposition 7.1. A `xoroshiro+` generator with w bits of output and kw bits of state applying the + scrambler (see Section 4.1) to the first and last word of state is (k−1)-dimensionally equidistributed. [...] Proposition 7.3. A `xoshiro+` generator with w bits of output and 4w bits of state applying the + scrambler (see Section 4.1) to the first and last word of state is 3-dimensionally equidistributed." See also: https://prng.di.unimi.it/

Comment: The [quality](https://prng.di.unimi.it/#quality) link on the documentation you cite has a fairly extensive discussion about this class of generators, albeit without the proofs found in formal peer-reviewed publications. They quite clearly state that all but one of the generators passes multiple runs of the BigCrush suite of tests, which consists of a wide variety of tests for uniformity, k-tuple uniformity, and serial correlation (linear dependence).